# Show shapefile data by Leaflet

Tags: shapefile, leaflet, leaflet-plugins

I am trying to load a shapefile in Leaflet but no luck, It just loads the map. not sure what I am missing.

Here is the file:
http://data-atgis.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/2ba102832e8b4d69a15e33e9a1c8d63a_0.zip

I have downloaded leadlet.shpfile.js, shp.js, catiline.js and saved them next to my HTML along with the shapefile as shown below.
[image]

and here is my HTML code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Esri Leaflet Quickstart</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />

  <!-- Load Leaflet from CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
    crossorigin=""/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
    crossorigin=""></script>

  <!-- Load Esri Leaflet from CDN -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@3.0.2/dist/esri-leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-myckXhaJsP7Q7MZva03Tfme/MSF5a6HC2xryjAM4FxPLHGqlh5VALCbywHnzs2uPoF/4G/QVXyYDDSkp5nPfig=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js" data-require="leaflet@0.7.3" data-semver="0.7.3"></script>


  <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
  </style>
  <script src="AT_2.geojson" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>
<script src="catiline.js"></script>
    <script src="leaflet.shpfile.js"></script>
    <script src="shp.js"></script>
<script>
var geo = L.geoJson({features:[]},{onEachFeature:function popUp(f,l){
            var out = [];
            if (f.properties){
                for(var key in f.properties){
                out.push(key+": "+f.properties[key]);
        }
        l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
    }
    }});
    
  var map = L.map('map').setView([-36.833891798833903,174.830803391713999], 11)
  L.esri.basemapLayer('Topographic').addTo(map);

var base = 'AT_Infrastructure_Projects.zip';
        shp(base).then(function(data){
        geo.addData(data);
        }).addTo(map);;
  shpfile.addTo(map);
    shpfile.once("data:loaded", function() {
        console.log("finished loaded shapefile");
    });     
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Since I need this map needs to be sent as an email attachment and js files are not allowed to be included as attachments, I have included those js files (catiline, shp,leaflet.shpfile.js) within  tags.
but I am receiving this error
[image]

Seems the solution for the above are available here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nx8E5BF0XuE
and here
https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches/
but none of the suggested solutions in the video works for me as I need my user to just open the html.file without changing anything on their system.

Comment: Any errors in the browse debugger console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code seems like a mixture of examples from various sources that of course does not work together. There are several reasons why it does not work:

- You have ages old `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.3/leaflet.js` Leaflet library reference at the end of references, which should go out.
- GeoJSON layer `geo` is never added to the map.
- `.addTo(map)` for `shp(base)` is wrong and shouldn't be there. Data is added to `geo` layer with `geo.addData(data)` statement.
- References to `shpfile` layer should go out, since there is no such layer.

Your code should then look something like this:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([-36.833891798833903,174.830803391713999], 11)
L.esri.basemapLayer('Topographic').addTo(map);

var geo = L.geoJson({features:[]}, {
  onEachFeature: function popUp(f, l) {
    var out = [];
    if (f.properties){
      for(var key in f.properties){
        out.push(key + ": " + f.properties[key]);
      }
      l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
    }
  }
}).addTo(map);

var base = 'AT_Infrastructure_Projects.zip';
shp(base).then(function(data){
  geo.addData(data);
});
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Are those js libraries (catiline.js) are available online as CDN?

Comment: If you look in the docs of `catiline.js` at https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/catiline, you'll see the following remark: **Important:** the file catiline.js or catiline.min.js should be a standalone file hosted on the same domain as your web page. If you can't, or need to bundle catiline but you need it to work on IE10, Opera, and Safari, you have to host the file "SHIM_WORKER.js" on the same domain as the html file and set the path to it in a global variable SHIM_WORKER_PATH before you load catiline.

Comment: If you have no problem with that, you can refer to it at https://unpkg.com/catiline@2.9.3/dist/catiline.js

Comment: Thanks, I included those between script tags, seems the problem has been solved, but I am receiving two errors related to cross-origin, trying to find a solution for this as well in Google.

Comment: To be fair, your solution seems working but I cannot get it done working on my system, I also upvoted it an hour ago. Since you seems unhappy, I now accept your solution although I am still having problem

Comment: If you have problems implementing the solution, post a new question with description of the problem.

Comment: @MohsenSichani Having had the same issue, the best approach I've found is to convert the shapefile to a geojson which you can store as a js file (with just `var data = {json data}` and include it via `<script>`. I don't see an easy solution to cross-origin problems using local shapefiles.